# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)" when using flask

Tags: python, html, flask, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with a web app am developing, am using python flask on the server side, and every time I run the python app I get a "Failed to load the resource, 404 page not found" error.

Here's the app schema:

```
\Libertas
    \static
        index.css
        index.js
        \images
    \templates
        Home.html
    app.py
```

And here's my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Home.html')

@app.route('/SubmitForm',methods=['POST'])
def SubmitForm():
    data = request.get_json()
    name, email, message = data['name'], data['email'], data['message']
    connection = sqlite3.connect("messages.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages(name TEXT,email TEXT,message TEXT)""")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES(?,?,?)",[name,email,message])
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    response = jsonify({'status': 'success', 'message': 'message added to the database successfully'})
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here's my Home.html code:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Libertas startup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#services/products">Services/Products</a>
            <a href="#team">Team</a>
            <a href="#connect">Connect</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="home" class="home">
        <h1>Libertas</h1>
        <p id="slogan"></p>
    </section>
    <section id="about" class="about">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <p>We are a startup that aims to make it easier for everyone to be a digital nomad.<br>We provide products and services that solves major problems that digital nomads face in their journey.<br>We believe that Freedom, location-independence, and divercifying experiences will be the core values of work and life in the future, so we just embraced those values because we believe in the future.</p>
        <img src="../static/images/5.jpg" id="about.image">
    </section>
    <section id="services/products" class="services">
        <h1>services & products</h1>
        <div class="commodities">
            <div class="commodity">
                <div class="name"><h1>Odyssey</h1></div>
                <div class="description"><p>An app that allows digital nomads to combine the flexibility of solo-travel and the socialization of group travel</p></div>
                <div class="preview"><img src="../static/images/6.png"></div>
                <div class="learn_more"><button>learn more</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="commodity">
                <div class="name"><h1>Nomad Space</h1></div>
                <div class="description"><p>A co-working space catered towards, and exclusive to Digital Nomads</p></div>
                <div class="preview"><img src="../static/images/7.jpg"></div>
                <div class="learn_more"><button>learn more</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="team" class="team">
        <h1>Team</h1>
        <div class="team_member">
            <div class="preview"><img src="../static/images/8.JPEG"></div>
            <div class="member_info">
                <div class="name"><h1>Moe Hasan</h1></div>
                <div class="position"><p>Founder, CEO, and CTO.</p></div>
                <div class="description"><p>Am an interdisciplinary, self-taught software developer, content creator on Youtube, Founder, and most importantly, A science lover.</p></div>
                <div class="connect">
                    <a href=""><img src="../static/images/10.svg"></a>
                    <a><img src="../static/images/11.svg"></a>
                    <a><img src="../static/images/12.svg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team_member">
            <div class="preview"><img src="../static/images/9.JPG"></div>
            <div class="member_info">
                <div class="name"><h1>We're Hiring!</h1></div>
                <div class="position"><p>CMO</p></div>
                <div class="description"><p>We need a cofounder who is willing to occupy the position of CMO.<br>for more info, please reach out to us via the form in the "connect" section.</p></div>
                <div class="connect">
                    <a><img src="../static/images/10.svg"></a>
                    <a><img src="../static/images/11.svg"></a>
                    <a><img src="../static/images/12.svg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team_member">
            <div class="preview"><img src="../static/images/9.JPG"></div>
            <div class="member_info">
                <div class="name"><h1>We're Hiring!</h1></div>
                <div class="position"><p>UX/UI expert</p></div>
                <div class="description"><p>We need a cofounder who is willing to occupy the position of chief UX/UI designer.<br>for more info, please reach out to us via the form in the "connect" section.</p></div>
                <div class="connect">
                    <a><img src="../static/images/10.svg"></a>
                    <a><img src="../static/images/11.svg"></a>
                    <a><img src="../static/images/12.svg"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="connect" class="connect">
        <form class="connect_form" id="connect_form" method="post" action="">
            <h1>connect with us</h1>
            <div class="customer_credentials">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="UserName">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="customer_message">
                <input type="text" placeholder="message" id="Message">
            </div>
            <h3 id="Error_Message" style="color: red;"></h3>
            <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" class="SubmitButton">
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="../static/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```


And here's my index.js code:

`
var i = 0;
var slogan = 'For a Free New World';
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < slogan.length) {
    document.getElementById('slogan').innerHTML += slogan.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 100);
  }
}
typeWriter()


const form = document.getElementById("connect_form")
const submit_button = document.getElementById("SubmitButton")
submit_button.addEventListener("click",SubmitForm)
//the function that sends the data to the server side after checking them
function SubmitForm(event){
    //stopping the form from refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
    //taking the inputs and storing them in variables
    let name = document.getElementById("UserName").value.trim();
    let email = document.getElementById("Email").value.trim();
    let message = document.getElementById("Message").value.trim();
    //checking the inputs using RegEx
    const nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
    const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/
    if(!nameRegex.test(name) || !emailRegex.test(email)){
        document.getElementById("Error_Message").innerHTML = "Please input valid Name and Email"
        form.reset();
    }
    else{
        //converting the data to JSON format before sending it to the server side
        const Object_Message = {"name":name,"email":email,"message":message}
        const Json_message = JSON.stringify(Object_Message)
        //sending the JSON formatted data to the server side
        fetch('/SubmitForm', {method: 'POST',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},body: Json_message,credentials:"include"})
        .then(response => {if (!response.ok) {throw new Error('Network response was not ok');}return response.json();})
        .then(data => {console.log('Response data:', data);})
        .catch(error => {console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);});
    }    
}
`
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple syntax error, missing the `@` before `app.route('/')` is the likely culprit.

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Home.html')
```